# Call result of PHP

Tags: php, html, dynamic, gallery, galleria

My problem is that I have a PHP that lists images in a folder (and it works fine; that's not the problem) but I don't know how to "call" the result in the HTML.

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
    $directory="img";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
    {
        if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo)){
            echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
        }
    }
    $dirint->close();
?>
```

And in my HTML I have:

```
<body>
    <div id="gallery">
<img src="photo1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <script>
        Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
        $("#gallery").galleria({

            width: 976,
            height: 350,
            show_imagenav:true
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

That works great, but I need to replace the `<img src="photo1.jpg" />` for the list that PHP creates.

How do I do it?

Comment: What happens when you you just replace `<img src="photo1.jpg" />` with your first code snippet?

Comment: FYI, [`eregi()` is deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php).  And I don't understand what you're asking...didn't you `echo` that `img` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to combine these two examples?

The HTML file has to be a PHP file or PHP has to parse the *.html or *.htm file. And then you just need to replace your '' with the PHP code snippet so that it becomes:

```
<body>
    <div id="gallery">
    <?php
        $directory="img";
        $dirint = dir($directory);
        while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
        {
            if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo)){
                echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
            }
        }
        $dirint->close();
    ?>
    </div>
    <script>
        Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
        $("#gallery").galleria({

            width: 976,
            height: 350,
            show_imagenav:true
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: OH GOD!!!! it was just that!!! change the html extension to php!!!! THANKS!!!! seriously!!! :D

Comment: mmm now I see that the code to list the folder, mades the list upside down, any ideas to change it? I mean that it show first picture number 3, 2, 1... and it should be 1, 2, 3... thanks!!!

Comment: You could use the function 'sort' to order the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert any PHP code directly into HTML - as long as you remember to include the opening and closing tags.

You might also need to rename your HTML file, if it is named e.g. index.html, to index.php so it will correctly process the PHP contained within it.

(I've assumed, from your question, that you're wondering about how to properly insert PHP functionality into HTML markup)

As the other answer says, if you just paste the PHP code directly in place of your image tag, that should work fine.